# Printing Stars based on input from Command Prompt

Tags: java, loops, command-prompt, args

I have bee assigned a project to print out patterns of stars. We are suppose to take a number given in the CMD and have it print out a pattern. Or atleast that's how I understand it.

---

Here is what the assignment says:

> Take a numeric input from the command line and produce the correct
>   number of stars and rows.

Example:

```
C:\java Stars 3
```

will produce,

```
*
**
***
```

---

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Stars1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int len = args.length;

         if( len <= 0)
         {
             System.out.println(" ERROR: Please input a value of 1-5");
             System.exit(0);
         }  

        int j;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println("");


        }


    }
}
```

I am trying to produce the pattern:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

The example code he showed us used args.length to echo back what ever was typed via Command Prompt. So if we typed in `C:\ java Echo I type, it types.` 
It would print out `I type, it types.`

Here is the code he told us to look at:

```
public class echo
{
    public static void sopl( String str )
    {
        System.out.println( "\t" + str );
    }

    public static void sop( String str )
    {
        System.out.print( str );
    }





    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int len = args.length;

        if( len == 0 )
        {
            sopl( "\n\tUsage: java echo <args:String[]>" );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }

        sop( "\n\t" );

        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) sop( args[i] + " " );

        sop( "\n\t" );

        while( len > 0 ) sop( args[args.length - len--] + " " );

        sopl( "" );
    }
```

How can I use the args.length to produce the pattern? I can get it to produce the pattern easily without having to take input form the command line.

Comment: `args.length` provides you with the number of command line arguments. Just making that clear...

Comment: do your assignment asks u to use args.length to produce the pattern? or it just want to take the input from commandline and produce

Comment: The code he told you to look at has poor formatting >.<

Comment: It asks us to  "Take a numeric input from the command line and produce the correct number of stars and rows." 
I am not sure if he actually wanted us to us args.length or not honestly.

Comment: I would assume that, in your example, he would want 3 stars to be printed instead of 1, but he may still want you to use a for loop to go through all the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Stars1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
System.out.println("Enter no of rows to be printed");

   int  row= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

          int len = args.length;

         if( len <= 0)
         {
             System.out.println(" ERROR: Please input a value of 1-5");
             System.exit(0);
         }  

        int j;
        for(int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println("");


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do it would be to use an Integer.parseInt(String); I'm not sure it will work with args.length unless args.length is made to be the length that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to point a couple things out...

Without the input, I assume you are changing the `4` in `i <= 4` to control the number of stars you are printing.

`args.length` is getting the length of the `String` array `args[]`, which using `C:\java Stars 3` would be `1`.

Note how his example code uses `args[i]`

```
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    sop( args[i] + " " );
}
```

`i` is an `int` and this is how he is getting the value within `args[]`

---

More on describing his code..

You call `C:\ java Echo I type, it types.`

```
public static void main( String[] args ) //args["I", "type,", "it", "types."]
{
    int len = args.length; //len = 4; (see above comment)

    if( len == 0 ) //in case no arguments are entered
    {
        sopl( "\n\tUsage: java echo <args:String[]>" );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }

    sop( "\n\t" ); //print new line and tab

    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) //start at 0, as long as i < 4, increment i after each loop
    {
        sop( args[i] + " " ); //print the arg: arg[0] = "I", arg[1] = "type,", etc..
    }

    sop( "\n\t" ); //print another new line and tab

    while( len > 0 ) sop( args[args.length - len--] + " " ); //same thing as for loop but going backwards and more confusing(just for the sake of using a while loop I assume). Changes the value of len

    sopl( "" ); //print tab
}
```

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks. I was having trouble trying to figure how to translate what he used in the example code to this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Stars1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int len = args.length;

         if( len <= 0)
         {
             System.out.println(" ERROR: Please input a value of 1-5");
             System.exit(0);
         }  

        int j;
        for(int i = 0; i <=len; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println("");


        }


    }
}
```